# Is using multiple replaces in a JS function 'good' practice?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have an area of my site which allows a user to enter a custom URL. The rules of the URL are that it must be alphanumeric with the exception of the hyphen character. If a hyphen is used, it cannot be successive and cannot start (or end) the string.

I use the following function to achieve this:

```
$('.url').bind("change keyup blur", function() {
     var url = $(this);

     url.val( url.val().replace(/[^A-z0-9-]/gi,'').replace(/-{2}/g,'-').replace(/^-/g,'') );
});
```

The function works well but I am wondering if it is good practice or possible to combine the rules into a single replace statement.

If successive hyphens (--) are used, a hyphen replaces it so I am thinking atleast 2 replace statements are needed.

### EDIT

I am getting a lot of responses to the question in the form of 'here is code you should use' and while I appreciate it, the function I have is working. I ultimately was giving an example of what I meant by multiple replace statements on a single value and if it was good/bad practice to do such.

I think giving the code hints or suggestion helps but not this is not a "how do I shorten this code" question.

Comment: As a side note, you're much better off blocking input than you are replacing it.  Changing the value of an element moves the caret to the end of the field in most browsers.  The code you have at the moment is an accessibility nightmare — just try using the arrow keys or shift-highlighting in those fields.

Comment: Do NOT use `A-z` to find `A-Z` and `a-z`, since several characters exist between `Z` and `a`.

Comment: @Pumbaa80, please explain. I actually modified from [A-Za-z0-9] to what I had so what characters exist between?

Comment: @Andy E - not sure what you mean. I can use the arrow keys just fine.

Comment: @JM4: did you test it in several browsers?  Most browsers will remove the caret.  Also, Pumbaa80 is correct.  Your regex will not remove certain characters like `_` and `[`.

Comment: @JM4: here's an example of what I mean (*move the caret*, not *remove*): http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/FGS2g/.  Type something in the box, then use the arrow keys to move backwards and forwards.  I've tested in Chrome and IE, and the caret position is always forced to the end.

Comment: @JM4: Try this snippet to list the characters `A-z` (or any other range actually): `for (var c = 'A'; c <= 'z'; c = String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt()+1)) { console.log(c); }`. You'll find `A-z` including `[\]^_\``

Comment: @AndyE, for one - your code is not valid as you replace every instance of a hyphen which mine does not do. It should replace a hyphen if at the first or end and only double hyphens elsewhere. What does it matter if it moves the cursor to the end of the text? The individual should be entering the url in real-time regardless so if they need to delete what they wrote and try again then so be it?

Comment: @JM4: it matters because if I make a mistake, I can't use the arrow keys to go back and fix it.  My regex **does not** replace every instance of a hyphen, you're just not using it right ;-)

Comment: So far, you don't seem very appreciative of the time anybody has taken to try and help you, you seem to be rather insisting that what you have is fine — if that's the case then why ask the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way you are doing it is fair enough. Regexes have a tendency to become hard-to-follow quite quickly. They also have a tendency to become wrong :)

However I would consider breaking the replacement routine out into a separate function..

Answer (score 4):

It's not particularly bad practice to use more than one replace function.  In fact, the [fastest compatibility implementations of trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript) use multiple replace statements because it's faster to have two separate regular expressions for searching at the start and end of strings than a combined expression that does both.

If you're not worried about performance, however, you *could* combine the expressions using `|`, with slight modification to use a positive lookahead instead of Daniel's suggestion of `-{2,}`:

```
url.val().replace(/[^A-Z0-9-]|-(?:-)|^-|-$/gi, '')
```

Comment: Your code is invalid. Entering a single hyphen with this code removes it. You also would need to set the value as: url.val( then code );

Comment: @JM4: yes, that was for you to work out for yourself, which you did.  And the code works fine, I tested it on several different strings, it does not remove single hyphens unless they appear at the beginning or end, as specified by your question.

Comment: @JM4 You comment on Andy's answer as though he is the one asking the question! :-S

Comment: @AndyE - While I appreciate your response, your code is not valid and removes all hyphens. I assume the code you have here is the code you entered in our comment to the question in the JSfiddle. Try entering "base-ball" and see what happens to the hyphen.

Comment: @ElRonnoco - I am not sure I follow what you are saying but I commented because from my testing it is code that doesn't work. If the purpose of SO is to provide good insight to fellow and future users, and I am expecte to choose the 'best' answer then it should be one that atleast uses valid code. I'll try it again but in three browsers it removes hyphens within text.

Comment: @JM4: sure, because when you type it, the hyphen is at the end and it is removed - which is what you asked for.   However, if you type *baseball*, then place the cursor just after the *e*, the regex will not remove a typed hyphen.  The same goes for pasting *base-ball*.  I answered the literal question with this answer, but like I said in the comments to your question, your approach is the real problem.

Comment: AndyE - you and I seem to disagree on the topic and that is fine. My approach to my own question was finding if something was bad practice. It seems consensus it was not. Although I appreciate your code efforts as well as others, they do NOT meet my requirements. The *multiple* replace is highlighted in your response. If a user cannot enter a hypehn at all (because it is at the end as your answer/comments suggest) that is a coding error. I use a SEPARATE function to clear the final hyphen (hence more than one replace, whether combined in this function or another).

Comment: @JM4: you're missing the point of the answer (and, perhaps Stack Overflow) entirely.  The intent was to answer your question in the first paragraph and make a suggestion for improvement in the second.  Nowhere did I say that you *should* use the code in the latter.  It was merely an attempt to show you that you can combine regular expression replacements if you don't like them being separate.

Comment: @AndyE And as my first comment on this showed, your answer(s) is/are incorrect regarding. If I stated a member can enter a hyphen within the url in the original question, which I did, then your answer is invalid because it negates the hyphen before the user can even type it. Arrow usage and the ability to copy/paste were also shown to be incorrect.

Comment: @JM4 I was making a point about the abrupt manner of your response to Andy's answer. For one, the code *is valid* as far as it is a JS expression which produces a value (providing `url` has been set correctly) - it may not be what you *wanted* but it's *valid*. Also, you proceeded to tell Andy what he needed to do to make the code work for you. If you know, you don't need to ask a question :) A *"Thanks, but..."* is always better than a *"You're wrong, and..."*

Answer (score 1):

You could say replace 2 or more hyphens.

```
.replace(/-{2,}/g,'-')
//           ^ notice the comma
```

Comment: it would be impossible to get to more than 2 hyphens given once the second one is entered it automatically deletes it.

Comment: @JM4: consider what happens when someone right clicks the box and chooses *Paste*.  It's entirely possible for someone to add more than one hyphen.

Comment: @AndyE, look at the code more closely. The JS function occurs on change, keyup and blur. Copy and pasting (yes I have tried this) will remove the extra hyphen(s) once clicked anywhere else on screen. While I understand JS can be disable and several other 'funky' exceptions, nobody can enter two hyphens in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

probably a single regex will be "a very little" faster, but with short text and three easy patterns as it is now, it is already fast enough.

no problem for me

Comment: Well micro optimization matters. These small things will get together and make a sea that takes more than 1 second to exec!